# Java Not Using a Static Variable

Tags: java, static, instance

I have the method `drawPoliticCard()` that i need to use in the method from another class `applyBonus()`, i can do it easily using a static attribute but the problem is that i should be able to run two instances of the game independently at the same time, so if use static both instances will be sharing the same deck of cards. That's why i wanted to know if there is a way to do it without using a static attribute. I'll omit the getters and setters of the attributes to make it more concise.

```
public class PoliticCard {
    private static ArrayList<Color> politicCards;

    public void setDeck(){
        setPoliticCards(new ArrayList<Color>());
            getPoliticCards().add(Color.BLACK);
            getPoliticCards().add(Color.PURPLE);
            getPoliticCards().add(Color.BLUE);
    }
    public static void drawPoliticCard(Player player){
        player.getPoliticCards().add(getPoliticCards().get(0));
        getPoliticCards().remove(0);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Bonus {
    protected int number;//The number of politic cards added in BonusPoliticCard
}
```

---

```
public class BonusPoliticCard extends Bonus {
    public BonusPoliticCard(int number) {
        this.number=number;
    }
    public void applyBonus(Player player){
        int i=0;
        while(i<number){
            PoliticCard.drawPoliticCard(player);
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

I know that to call a method from another function you should create a new instance of the class, but if i do i get an `nullpointerexception` when testing.

```
public class BonusPoliticCard extends Bonus {
    public BonusPoliticCard(int number) {
        this.number=number;
    }
    public void applyBonus(Player player){
        int i=0;
        while(i<number){
            PoliticCard politicCard = new PoliticCard();
            politicCard.drawPoliticCard(player);
            i++;
        }
    }

}

public class BonusPoliticCardTest {

    @Test
    public void testBonusPoliticCard() {//This ran fine when it was static
        Bonus bonus = new BonusPoliticCard(3);
        Player player = new Player(1);
        PoliticCard politicCard = new PoliticCard();
        politicCard.setDeck();
        bonus.applyBonus(player);
        assertNotNull(player.getPoliticCards().get(2));

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you write stack trace?

Comment: Where is your main method? Take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Do you have two accounts or are you working on this same code as this other user?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37597778/java-calling-a-method-without-creating-an-instance

Comment: @Gendarme doesn't a test count as a main? you can run it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Player class is not shown in the problem, there are two cases where NullPointerException can be thrown:

(1) PoliticCard instance created in BonusPoliticCardTest is different from the instance you create in BonusPoliticCard class. So the politicCards arrayList that you set via politicCard.setDeck() inside BonusPoliticCardTest is never going to be available with PoliticCard instance you create inside BonusPoliticCard class. Also note that the politicCards arrayList of PoliticCard instance is both created and set inside setDeck(). So, during the call to bonus.applyBonus(player); the politicCards arrayList reference points to null, hence NullPointerException will be thrown at following line for getPoliticCards().get(0):

```
player.getPoliticCards().add(getPoliticCards().get(0)); // inside drawPoliticCard(Player player) method
```

(2) Player class should have ArrayList politicCards created inside its constructor otherwise we would get NullPointerException on the following line for player.getPoliticCards().add(...):

```
player.getPoliticCards().add(getPoliticCards().get(0)); // inside drawPoliticCard(Player player) method
```

Here is the correct code sample:

PoliticCard.java

```
public class PoliticCard {
    private ArrayList<Color> politicCards;

    /**
     * @return the politicCards
     */
    public ArrayList<Color> getPoliticCards() {
        return politicCards;
    }
    /**
     * @param politicCards the politicCards to set
     */
    public void setPoliticCards(ArrayList<Color> politicCards) {
        this.politicCards = politicCards;
    }

    public void setDeck() {
        setPoliticCards(new ArrayList<Color>());
        getPoliticCards().add(Color.BLACK);
        getPoliticCards().add(Color.PURPLE);
        getPoliticCards().add(Color.BLUE);
    }

    public void drawPoliticCard(Player player) {
        player.getPoliticCards().add(getPoliticCards().get(0));
        getPoliticCards().remove(0);
    }

}
```

Bonus.java:

```
public class Bonus {
    protected int number; //The number of politic cards added in BonusPoliticCard
}
```

BonusPoliticCard.java

```
public class BonusPoliticCard extends Bonus {
    PoliticCard politicCard;
    public BonusPoliticCard(int number, PoliticCard politicCard) {
        this.number=number;
        this.politicCard = politicCard;
    }
    public void applyBonus(Player player){
        int i=0;
        while(i<number){
            politicCard.drawPoliticCard(player);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Player.java

```
public class Player {
    private ArrayList<Color> politicCards;
    int num;

    public Player(int num) {
        this.num = num;
        politicCards = new ArrayList<Color>();
    }

    /**
     * @return the politicCards
     */
    public ArrayList<Color> getPoliticCards() {
        return politicCards;
    }

    /**
     * @param politicCards the politicCards to set
     */
    public void setPoliticCards(ArrayList<Color> politicCards) {
        this.politicCards = politicCards;
    }
}
```

BonusPoliticCardTest.java

```
public class BonusPoliticCardTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        PoliticCard politicCard = new PoliticCard();
        politicCard.setDeck();
        Bonus bonus = new BonusPoliticCard(3, politicCard);
        Player player = new Player(1);
        ((BonusPoliticCard) bonus).applyBonus(player);
        assertNotNull(player.getPoliticCards().get(2));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of class PoliticCard inside a constructor of class Bonus. So you will be able to use them together and create multiple instances of the game also:

```
public class BonusPoliticCard extends Bonus {
    PoliticCard p;
    public BonusPoliticCard(int number) {
        this.number=number;
        p = new PoliticCard();
    }
    public void applyBonus(Player player){
        int i=0;
        while(i<number){
            p.drawPoliticCard(player);
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i still get the same error, isn't that because the `new PoliticCard();` in `BonusPoliticCard` creates another instance of `PoliticCard` and doesn't use the one created in the test `PoliticCard politicCard = new PoliticCard();`?(sorry, but there was an error before in while, it should be while(i<number))

Answer (score 0):

I am little bit confused with your code design, I have following concerns -

1. As per the name of class - BonusPoliticCard, It should extend PoliticCard class. `BonusPoliticCard extends PoliticCard` makes more sense.
2. Do we really need Bonus class to just keep the count of politic cards added in BonusPoliticCard. In my opinion, If Bonus class is needed, then I think there should HAS-A relationship between PoliticCard and Bonus. `PoliticCard HAS-A BONUS`.
3. We should generally avoid the use of statics,unless they are really needed. If we are thinking that we need statics, then we should really think again and again on the requirement and design, then only we should go for statics. For utility classes, we can go for statics.
   I found one useful article on this [here](https://dzone.com/articles/why-static-bad-and-how-avoid).

So in my opinion you should think once more on your design. My answer is on the basis of the code provided only.

Comment: Good suggestions. Maybe you can answer the question as well?

Comment: BonusPoliticClass is a subclass of bonus because there are different type of bonus, i have trouble with this bonus in particular because it calls a method from a different class several times, the other bonus only change the values of the attributes of the class `Player`, no bonus also have all the other attributes used in the other types of bonus, i only put number because it's the attribute used in `BonusPoliticCard`